# Iranian/Danish dual citizen going from Denmark to USA to study

Tags: usa, student-visa, study, danish-citizens

I was born in Iran and moved to Denmark. I have a Iranian Passport, Danish passport, and Danish citizenship. I study at a Danish university, and I want to go to USA to study. However, I'm worried that there may occur problems since I was born in Iran or because I have an Iranian passport.

I have visited Iran multiple times, last time was in 2015. How can I find out if it is possible for me to study in USA?

Answer (score 2):

Iranian citizens can study in the US, typically via an F1 visa. See https://ir.usembassy.gov/visas/faqs/ for more information. The most frequent process is 1) apply to US school 2) upon acceptance, their international student office will guide you, as you need some document from them to apply for an F1 visa.

Answer (score 2):

As [Franck writes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/157227/94507), Iranian citizens are eligible for student visas even with the restrictions on most visas currently in effect for Iranians.

However, as you say you are also a Danish citizen, you will probably find the process smoother if you apply with your Danish passport. According to the [DHS FAQ](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2017/03/06/qa-protecting-nation-foreign-terrorist-entry-united-states) (question #22), dual citizens traveling on their non-restricted passport are allowed to come to the US.

Notwithstanding this, you might unfortunately find the process to go more slowly and stressfully than for students without a connection to Iran. The school you are attending in the US should be able to try to help you through the process, though their powers may be limited in the face of excessive feet-dragging from the immigration bureaucracy.